# How to map nested array structure data to prop in react-redux

Tags: react-redux

I currently have a nested array structure data (think of it as items under a sub category under a category) which is like:

```
[
   {
      category:"c1",
      subcategories: [{name: "sc1", items: [{name: "i1"}]}...]
   }
   ...
]
```

I want to build a menu component by building category component, subcategory component, and item component, When I use react-redux `connect()`, I wonder how can I connect each level of the component to map according the level of data structure? The current design just simply maps the whole data to menu level, and pass by props to each level of component, but this way lost the point of using react-redux

Comment: I would do this too. Categories are an array. So using `.map` makes sense

Comment: @UG_ Thanks, so you mean total not necessary to use react-redux?

Comment: Yes! I use react & redux at work and in such situation I just pass redux state (array) to highest component and use map

Comment: @UG_ But when u update data in very low data level such as clicking in item level(which dispatch action), u just manually dispatch action in that component using `store.dispatch` without any react-redux helper?

Comment: In that case you use `connect` but pass empty mapStateToProps and pass actionCreator only in mapDispatchToProps

Comment: @UG_  this is what my confuse lying, if nothing for mapStateToProps, when I dispatch action, how can I tell redux store what data to update(there need to be a reference to according data)?

Comment: Ideally!! you would have the id of the record to be in updated in the action object, wont you ? 
You can then use `array.map(obj => obj.id===action.id ? return updatedObj : obj)` in the reducer

Comment: @UG_ So u mean I need to keep passing category id along with subcategory id along item id down until it reach item level?

Comment: Yes there has to be some identifier, right ? Or else how would you update in array ?

Comment: @UG_ If so, how can I update the according data in reducer? First, loop through to search category level, find according category with that id, then into subcategory level, loop through again to find according subcategory then into subcat, loop through again to find that item and update it? This seems inefficient... Also, BTW, if I need to build that reducer using combineReducers, how could I do that?

Comment: You are right!!
If you see combine reducer is used for nesting nested state `objects` and not arrays

If you make your categories an object instead of array, it would make more sense to use combinereducer and separate mapStatetoProps